# Podio C# how to get Contact from an item

Tags: c#, podio

I got an item by `item = client.ItemService.GetItem(itemid);`

then the item has a field with type Contact. How can I get it?

if it's a text field I can use `var textField = item.Field<Podio.API.Utils.ItemFields.TextItemField>(app.Fields[0].ExternalId)`

but for contact I cannot find such a method.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used podio, but after a quick look at the [documentation](https://developers.podio.com/clients/dotnet) maybe you can try this:

```
var contacts = item.Field<Podio.API.Utils.ItemFields.ContactItemField>(app.Fields[0].ExternalId).Contacts;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Client Library](https://github.com/podio/podio-dotnet).

Please refer Documentation Link for Podio C# Library [here](http://podio.github.io/podio-dotnet/fields/#contact-field)

Sample code for getting contact

```
    var item = podio.ItemService.GetItemBasic(123);
ContactItemField contactField = item.Field<ContactItemField>("client");
IEnumerable<Contact> contacts = contactField.Contacts;
```

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: Have edited the comment, but it's the sample code sample from the reference, anyways thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Something Like This

```
PodioAPI.Utils.ItemFields.ContactItemField contactField = item.Field<PodioAPI.Utils.ItemFields.ContactItemField>("Enter contact field id");
IEnumerable<PodioAPI.Models.Contact> myContact= contactField.Contacts;

foreach (var contact in myContact)
{
     string name = contact.Name;
     string user_id= contact.UserId;
}
```